# Can I travel to Japan with a US Travel Document Reentry Permit and my expired Venezuelan passport?

Tags: visas, usa, japan, military

Can I travel to Japan with a US travel document (reentry permit) and my expired Venezuelan passport? I am a military dependent with orders to travel there.
Can they put my Japanese visa there?
My passport expired and I won’t be able to renew it. USA considers it valid but not Japan.

Comment: As a **military dependent with orders to travel there**, you should recieve a valid document to make such travel possible. Talk to those that issued that order first, is my advice.

Comment: Do you have a US military ID?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://traveldoc.aero, you can board a flight to Japan with only a US military identification and your travel orders.  You can also board a flight to the US with only those documents, or only with the re-entry permit.  So, if you have a military ID in addition to the documents you mention, which I suppose you probably do, you should be fine to make this trip without renewing your passport and without applying for a Japanese visa.

> Tokyo Narita International Airport
>
> Japan
>
> Visa is not required for passengers holding military identification cards issued by the United States, with orders.

> Los Angeles (CA) International Airport
>
> United States of America
>
> Visa is not required for United States of America.

I omit a bunch of stuff about COVID-19.